# Up to date tutorial of FormsAuthentication in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm not getting to hang of the entire FormAuthentication thing. Is there an up-to-date tutorial somewhere? I found [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2008/02/07/asp-net-mvc-framework-using-forms-authentication.aspx), but it a bit old and the syntax doesn't match recent Asp.Net MVC.

Comment: Where are you experiencing issues? The template that VS2008 creates for an MVC project has Form authentication by default. It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Couldn't really find a new tutorial but if you post a new question with what you're having problems with someone on here will be glad to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Account Controller that a new ASP.NET MVC project creates.  It should already have everything you need to get started.